# java regex for validating a string?

Tags: java, regex, numeric

Hello guys i want to write a regex to check if a value has only numbers but 0 not to be in first position . for example the value 10 is correct but the value 01 is wrong.

so far i have this `mystr.matches("[123456789]+")`

Comment: `mystr.matches("[1-9]+")`

Comment: Is `0` a correct number?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm asking about `0`, just `0`

Comment: What about floating point numbers, like 10.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mystr.matches("^[1-9]\\d*$")
```

Comment: You need to escape the \ character by using \\.

Comment: Thanks, changed it, apparently I have to put in three \ characters in for it to show two.

Comment: `matches` will return true only if **entire** string matches used regex so there is no need for `^` and `$` :). Also try using "`{}`" key (or Ctrl+K) next time while creating answer to format selected code and you wont have to use tricks like \\\ to get two backslashes :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that one should do the job: `"([1-9]+[0-9]*)"`

Cheers!

Comment: you don't need + in your regex since you have `*` after [0-9]. Try to avoid [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Answer (score 2):

Proposed solution:

```
mystr.matches("[1-9]\\d*")
```

Explanation:

- `[1-9]` in the beginning to check if the first digit is between 1 and 9.
- `\\d*` to look for any digit (form 0 to 9).

Comment: how about 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ? Should be \\d* no?

Comment: when i put 2 i have problem

Comment: @user1884030 answer updated. By the way, is `0` a legal input?

Comment: This will match anything with a number (1-9) in it.

Answer (score 2):

All answers here will validate numbers like 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11, ... but in case you want to also include simple `0` but not `00`, `01` and so on you can use

```
mystr.matches("0|[1-9][0-9]*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this regex

```
^(?!0)\d+$
```